# Rails: How to change progress color under address bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<form action="/result" method="GET"> 
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

When I click a submit button with above code, the browser shows blue progress bar under address bar .

[image: like this]

I wanna change this default blue color into others.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue progress bar is present because you might have enabled Turbolinks in your application. To change the color or height of the progress bar you can simply write a CSS. like so

```
.turbolinks-progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```